# Sum of a Sequence Rules

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've been asked to write out and simplify the following sequence:

$$ \sum_{r=1}^4 \frac{a}{m} $$

The answerbook states that the solution is $\frac{4a}{m}$, but I don't understand why.

I know that there is a rule:

$$ \sum_{1}^n c =nc $$

Why is this rule this way; what is the reasoning behind it?

EDIT: Is it simply defined to be that way, without specific reasons?

Comment: If you add up the same thing n times. Than you get n-times that same thing. Make sense? If you want, you can prove that by induction via the definition of $\sum$.

Comment: Ah yeah.... very obvious now that you've put it like that. Thanks

Comment: Almost no mathematical "convention" is done without reason. For example, $0!=1$ because, there are $3!=6$ ways to order three elements — $(123),(132),(213),(231),(312),(321)$; $2!=2$ ways to order two elements — $(12),(21)$; and $1!=1$ way to order one element — $(1)$. Now, there is only one way to order zero elements, namely $()$. So $0!=1$. (Also all our rules would break if it weren't true. :P The same goes for the equation in your post.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint
$$ \sum_{r=1}^n a = \underbrace{a + \ldots + a}_{n \  \text{times}}$$

Answer (score 1):

This rule is actually quite intuitive, if you were to actually write out $\sum_{1}^n c =nc$ You would get $c+c+c+...+c$ with $n$ $c$'s, which is simply $nc$.

Remember that the summation notation is simply a shorthand for expressing long, extended sums and thus, intuitively, the notation follows the same rules as normal addition.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to think of it as a rule, but intuitively based on the mathematical meaning. We're summing $a/m$ from $r=1$ to $4$. But r doesn't appear anywhere in $a/m$, so we're effectively just summing 4 terms, all of which are $a/m$.